# AlarmManager PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE return not null after cancelling alarm

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm writing `Android` application in `Kotlin`. In some situations I'm using there `AlarmManager` to schedule task every 1 minute to do some action and in some condition cancel future calls.

Before setting up alarm I'm checking if it was already scheduled by using flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` so I wouldn't do it few times. At first it's working fine and there is in log

`Should set up repeating alarm: true`

But when I cancel my alarm and then I try do schedule it again it always return `false`. I would expect that after cancelling it I should again get `true` there which would indicate that there's no scheduled alarm for this `PendingIntent` operation. Is there something wrong with my code or with the way I think? :)

Here's my 2 methods used to set up and cancel alarm.

```
fun setupAlarm(context: Context) {
    val alarmMgr = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(context.applicationContext, ScheduledCheckReceiver::class.java)
    val existingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.applicationContext, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
    Log.d("AlarmUtil","Should set up repeating alarm: " + (existingIntent == null))
    if(existingIntent == null) {
        val alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.applicationContext, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        Log.d("AlarmUtil", "Setting up alarm to " + Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 1000))
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 1000, 60 * 1000, alarmIntent)
    }
}

fun cancelAlarm(context: Context) {
    Log.d("AlarmUtil", "Cancel alert called")
    val alarmMgr = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(context.applicationContext, ScheduledCheckReceiver::class.java)
    val alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.applicationContext, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After canceling the alarm you need to cancel the `PendingIntent`. After

```
alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent)
```

add

```
alarmIntent.cancel()
```

Comment: And were you able to fix this? I'm confused why this solution does not work for you and would like to know more.

Comment: Its not working for me too.
loAlarmMgrHalf.cancel(loAlarmIntentHalf)
loAlarmIntentHalf.cancel()

Comment: @RaRa please open a new question for your problem and include the relevant details.

Comment: If only the documentation was more evident, spend a whole lot trying to figure why this was not working and finally your suggestion helped.